# What formulas for the physics concept kinematics could be useful when calculating people traveling towards eachother

Tags: kinematics

For example two people are driving towards each other, both of their speeds are given and they are 80 km away from each other. One left right away and the other left after 10 minutes.
What physics concepts should I apply to better understand the way speed and time work for kinematics

Comment: As I mentioned in your earlier posting, this is not a physics related question. It is just normal math.  Speed x time will give you the answer.  It is only when they travel at near the speed of light that this becomes a physics related question.

Comment: I disagree with that statement. Physics is not just the study of objects near the speed of light. It is a broad field that encompasses a wide range of phenomena, including mechanics, thermodynamics, electromagnetism, quantum mechanics, and cosmology, among others. These different areas of physics all involve the study of objects and systems at various speeds, not just near the speed of light. In fact, many everyday phenomena, such as friction and gravity, can be studied and explained through the principles of physics.

Comment: Yes you are correct in your statement. But looking at the question posted in your other question, unless that question came from a fourth year physics textbook, I don't think they were really looking for all of those things. In any case your question becomes far far to general for this forum. You should narrow it down to one very specific topic and repost your question.

Comment: You need distance = speed * time, like foolishmuse said. Perhaps you are having a problem with the mixed units such as mph and minutes in your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/746254/destination-in-between-two-people-going-at-different-speeds).